# Why is the automatic transaction option in CakePHP is called "atomic"?

Tags: cakephp, transactions, cakephp-3.0, atomic

I do not understand the meaning of the word "atomic". For example:

```
$conn = $this->ArticlesTable->connection();
$articles->save($entity, ['atomic' => false]); // <-- here
$conn->commit();
```

Should it not be be "autocommit" instead?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're actually turning on/off "atomic" transactions, not "automatic" transactions.

"Atomic" is the correct term:

> An atomic transaction is an indivisible and irreducible series of
>   database operations such that either all occur, or nothing occurs. A
>   guarantee of atomicity prevents updates to the database occurring only
>   partially, which can cause greater problems than rejecting the whole
>   series outright.

-[Wikipedia: Atomicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems))

The key there is "...such that either ALL occur, or NOTHING occurs."

**When atomic is `false` (off)**, and you run a save that requires more than one query, it will run each individually and could be successful on some, but not others.

**When atomic is `true` (on)**, and you run a save that requires more than one query, it will process them as a single transaction, and either complete all successfully or fail all completely.  No partial saves/updates.